# Linux : error loading libraries from /usr/local/lib

Tags: linux, path, arm, shared-libraries

I have an ARM embedded system running Debian Wheezy.  Some of the functionality of our custom written apps is separated into shared library files.  We store our shared library files under /usr/local/lib.

The problem I am seeing is that one of our binaries is not starting up correctly as it can't load one of the shared libs from /usr/local/lib:

> /usr/local/bin/daemon_watchdog: error while loading shared libraries: libroots-base.so.5.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The file libroots-base.so.5.3 exists in /usr/local/lib.  /usr/local/lib should be getting searched for libraries, as we have added an extra file in the directory /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ to specifically include /usr/local/lib.  I've also run ldconfig to refresh the cache.

One clue could be that the file libroots-base.so.5.3 itself depends on other shared libraries.  If I run an "ldd libroots-base.so.5.3" in /usr/local/lib, it shows that several of the referenced libraries are not being picked up:

```
    libboost_log.so.1.43.0 => not found
    libboost_thread.so.1.43.0 => not found
    libboost_system.so.1.43.0 => not found
    libPocoUtil.so.11 => not found
    libPocoFoundation.so.11 => not found
    libPocoDataSQLite.so.11 => not found
    libPocoData.so.11 => not found
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgthread-2.0.so.0
```

(0x402f1000)
        libdbus-glib-1.so.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdbus-glib-1.so.2
(0x4005c000)

However, the files listed as not found are definitely present in /usr/local/lib, e.g.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 821784 Nov 22 21:29 libboost_log.so.1.43.0
```

Furthermore if I manually set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/local/lib after the system has booted, I can run our binaries fine.

Can anyone suggest what could be wrong?

Comment: Wrong architecture?  What does **file libboost_log.so.1.43.0** tell you?

Comment: Try running your binary with `LD_DEBUG=all` and see if the output contains any clues.  (`LD_DEBUG=help` might be useful for reducing the output.)

Comment: Are you setting /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ for hard-float linker?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys.  @tink the libboost file is for ARMHF which is my target.  auselen not sure what you mean.  scott I'm experimenting with those options, no solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest what could be wrong?

If setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` solves the problem, it's almost certain that you didn't add `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` correctly.

Which file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` did you add to?

Maybe you have a typo, or a trailing space, or *something*.

Comment: My etc/ld.so.conf contains "include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf", and there is an extra .conf file that our software install adds that has the contents of "/usr/local/lib".  I can't see any trailing spaces or other malformed content on the file.

Comment: I removed all my custom built packages then re-added them, and the problem has gone away.  Thanks everyone for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

While installing a library into /usr/local/lib, I get the following valuable hint. I used the option with `LD_RUN_PATH' and it works fine.

```
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
```